# How i can read tty file with timeout?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eof, tty

I have tty device in /dev , where I send AT commands. I want to read line by line and stop reading file after timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the program `stty` to configure the tty device. To see the settings for terminal /dev/ttyS0, try

`stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0`

The default settings regarding timeout are `min = 1; time = 0`, which means that the reading program will read until at least one character has been read and there is no timeout. Using e.g.

`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 min 0 time 10`

the reading program (e.g. `cat`) will finish reading after one second whether anything has been read or not. The unit for the parameter `time` is tenths of a second; you can check out `man stty` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling some info from [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/exit-script-by-timeout-if-delay-of-read-input-in-command-line.15905/), you can have a script in the sorts of:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SPECIFYING THE SERIAL PORT
SERIAL=ttyS0

#SETTING UP AN ERROR FLAG
FLAG="GO"

#OPENING SERIAL PORT FOR READING
exec 99</dev/${SERIAL} 

#READING FROM SERIAL
while ["${FLAG}" == "GO" ]
do 
    #IF NO INPUT IS READ AFTER 5 SECONDS, AN ERROR FLAG IS RAISED
    read -t 5 INPUT <&99
    STATUS=$?
    if test $STATUS -ne 0;
    then
      FLAG="ERROR"
    fi
done

#CLOSING SERIAL PORT
exec 99>&-
```

While FLAG==GO, the script will read one line at a time from the serial port. The STATUS variable gets the return of READ command. According to the [manual](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) READ will return anything different than 0 if the specified timeout is reached; when that happens, FLAG is updated, exiting the read loop.

Comment: Works like a charm, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.